# Video stutters when multiple clients requests the stream from the same rtsp source

Tags: python, gstreamer, encode, rtsp

I have one rtsp server with multiple videos hosted using multiprocessing queues as channels using sensor factory objects using gstreamer. The reason for using multi processing queue is because of the limitation of nvh264enc encoder in the pipeline(The teardown causes the ports to be nonusable in subsequent client connections, no problem in x264enc). The problem happens when multiple clients are connected to the same link, even though the factory is shared between clients with same media element. This problem occurs. The results can be seen in clients such as vlc player.

```py
"""
This module will provide encoder functionality
"""

from base64 import decode
from gc import get_stats
from os import stat
from queue import Empty
import sys
import itertools
import numpy as np
import logging
import threading
import multiprocessing as mp
import gi
from pprint import pprint

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0') 
gi.require_version('GstRtspServer', '1.0')

from gi.repository import Gst, GstRtspServer, GObject, GLib
import cv2
import subprocess
import time




GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)

# def on_debug(category, level, dfile, dfctn, dline, source, message, user_data):
#     if source:
#         print('Debug {} {}: {}'.format(
#             Gst.DebugLevel.get_name(level), source.name, message.get()))
#     else:
#         print('Debug {}: {}'.format(
#             Gst.DebugLevel.get_name(level), message.get()))

# if not Gst.debug_is_active():
#     Gst.debug_set_active(True)
#     level = Gst.debug_get_default_threshold()
#     Gst.debug_set_default_threshold(Gst.DebugLevel.INFO)
    # if level < Gst.DebugLevel.ERROR:
    #     Gst.debug_set_default_threshold(Gst.DebugLevel.WARNING)
    # Gst.debug_add_log_function(on_debug, None)
    # Gst.debug_remove_log_function(Gst.debug_log_default)


logging.basicConfig(
level=logging.DEBUG,
format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s',
handlers=[logging.FileHandler('GPU_enabled_frame_encode.log'), logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)])

logging.debug('Debug message')
logging.info('Info message')
logging.warning('Warning message')
logging.error('Error message')
logging.critical('Critical message')


class SensorFactory(GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory):
    def __init__(self, fps, img_shape, cols, verbosity=1, cap=None, speed_preset='medium', properties={}):
        super(SensorFactory, self).__init__(**properties)
        logging.info("sensory factory")
        self.rtsp_media = None
        self.height = int(img_shape[0])
        self.width = int(img_shape[1] * cols)
        self.number_frames = 0
        self.stream_timestamp = 0.0
        self.timestamp = time.time()
        self.dt = 0.0
        self.streamed_frames = 0
        self.verbosity = verbosity
        fps = int(fps)
        self.cap = cap
        self.appsrc = None
        # duration of a frame in nanoseconds nvh264enc x264enc
        self.duration = 1.0 / fps * Gst.SECOND
        key_int_max = ' key-int-max={} '.format(fps)
        caps_str = 'caps=video/x-raw,format=BGR,width={},height={},framerate={}/1 '.format(self.width,
                                                                                           self.height,
                                                                                           fps)
        self.launch_string = 'appsrc name=source is-live=true block=true do-timestamp=true \
            format=GST_FORMAT_TIME ' + caps_str + \
                             ' ! queue' \
                             ' ! videoconvert' \
                             ' ! video/x-raw,format=I420' \
                             ' ! nvh264enc' \
                             ' ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 name=pay0' \
                             ''


    def set_cap(self, cap):
        self.cap = cap

    def on_need_data(self, src, length):
        # this method executes when client requests data
        # logging.info("this method executes when client requests data")
        # if self.cap.isOpened():
        #     _, frame = self.cap.get_frame()
        #     ret = True

        if self.cap.isOpened():
            frame_queue = self.cap.get_queue()
            frame = frame_queue.get()
            ret = True
            if ret:
                if frame.shape[:2] != (self.height, self.width):
                    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.width, self.height))
                data = frame.tostring()
                buf = Gst.Buffer.new_allocate(None, len(data), None)
                buf.fill(0, data)
                buf.duration = self.duration
                timestamp = self.number_frames * self.duration
                buf.pts = buf.dts = int(timestamp)
                buf.offset = timestamp
                self.number_frames += 1
                retval = self.appsrc.emit('push-buffer', buf)
                # print('pushed buffer, frame {}, duration {} ns, durations {} s'.format(self.number_frames,
                                                                                    #   self.duration,
                                                                                    #   self.duration / Gst.SECOND))
                if retval != Gst.FlowReturn.OK:
                    logging.info("[INFO]: retval not OK: {}".format(retval))
                if retval == Gst.FlowReturn.FLUSHING:
                    logging.info('Offline')
            elif self.verbosity > 0:
                logging.info("[INFO]: Unable to read frame from cap.")
                # time.sleep(0.05)

    def do_create_element(self, url):
        if self.verbosity > 0:
            request_uri = url.get_request_uri()
            logging.info('[INFO]: stream request on {}'.format(request_uri))
        return Gst.parse_launch(self.launch_string)

    def do_configure(self, rtsp_media):
        self.rtsp_media = rtsp_media
        rtsp_media.set_reusable(True)
        self.number_frames = 0
        self.appsrc = rtsp_media.get_element().get_child_by_name('source')
        # executes when client requests data
        self.appsrc.connect('need-data', self.on_need_data)

    def get_rtsp_media(self):
        if self.rtsp_media:
            return self.rtsp_media
    
    def __del__(self):
        print('Destructor called, factory deleted.')


class RTSP_utility_server(GstRtspServer.RTSPServer):
    def __init__(self, fps, suffix='test', rtp_port=8554,
                 ip='12.0.0.0', caps=(None,), Sizes=[[1080, 1920]],
                 speed_preset='medium', verbosity=1, Indexes=[]):
        GObject.threads_init()
        Gst.init(None)
        super(RTSP_utility_server, self).__init__(**{})
        self.verbosity = verbosity
        self.rtp_port = "{}".format(rtp_port)
        if int(self.rtp_port) < 1024 and self.verbosity > 0:
            logging.info(
                '[INFO]: Note, admin privileges are required because port number < 1024.')
        self.set_service(self.rtp_port)
        self.speed_preset = speed_preset
        self.caps = caps
        self.factory = [None] * len(self.caps)
        self.suffix = suffix
        self.fps = fps
        self.Sizes = Sizes
        self.Indexes = Indexes
        self.attach(None)
        self.ip = self.get_ip()
        self.media_path_list = [None] * len(self.caps)
        self.clients_list = []

        if len(self.suffix):
            self.full_suffix = '/' + self.suffix.lstrip('/')
        else:
            self.full_suffix = ''

        self.connect("client-connected", self.client_connected)
        logging.info(
            '[INFO]: streaming on:\n\trtsp://{}:{}/{}#'.format(self.ip, self.rtp_port, self.suffix))

        self.status_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.status_thread_loop)
        self.status_thread.daemon = True
        self.status_thread.start()
        self.context = GLib.MainContext()
        print(self.attach(self.context))

    def set_caps(self, caps):
        if not isinstance(caps, (list, tuple)):
            caps = [caps]
        self.caps = caps

    def create_media_factories(self):
        mount_points = self.get_mount_points()
        media_path_list = []
        for i, cap in enumerate(self.caps):
            img_shape = self.Sizes[i]
            if len(self.Indexes) == 0:
                N_Index = str(i + 1)
            else:
                N_Index = str(self.Indexes[i])
            factory = SensorFactory(fps=self.fps, img_shape=img_shape, speed_preset=self.speed_preset,
                                    cols=1, verbosity=self.verbosity, cap=cap)
            factory.set_shared(True)
            factory.set_stop_on_disconnect(True)

            logging.info('inside media_factories Stream on ' +
                         self.full_suffix + N_Index)
            logging.info('inside media_factories Stream on ' +
                         self.full_suffix + N_Index)

            mount_points.add_factory(self.full_suffix + N_Index, factory)
            self.factory[i] = factory
            media_path_list.append(self.full_suffix + N_Index)
            self.media_path_list = media_path_list
        self.get_status()

    def destroy_media_factories(self):
        session_pool = self.get_session_pool()
        logging.info("Number of sessions are :" +
                     str(session_pool.get_n_sessions()))
        sessions_list = session_pool.filter()
        for session in sessions_list:
            for path in self.get_paths():
                media_matched, _ = session.get_media(path)
                if media_matched:
                    rtsp_media = media_matched.get_media()
                    rtsp_media.set_eos_shutdown(True)
                    rtsp_media.unprepare()
                    logging.debug("media removed for path "+path)
        number_of_disconnects = session_pool.cleanup()
        if number_of_disconnects > 0:
            logging.info("number of disconnects:"+str(number_of_disconnects))


    def destroy_media_factories_by_path(self,path_to_remove="/video1"):
        session_pool = self.get_session_pool()
        logging.info("Number of sessions are :" +
                     str(session_pool.get_n_sessions()))
        sessions_list = session_pool.filter()
        for session in sessions_list:
            for path in self.get_paths():
                media_matched, _ = session.get_media(path)
                if media_matched and path==path_to_remove:
                    rtsp_media = media_matched.get_media()
                    rtsp_media.set_eos_shutdown(True)
                    rtsp_media.unprepare()
                    logging.debug("media removed for path "+path)
        number_of_disconnects = session_pool.cleanup()
        if number_of_disconnects > 0:
            logging.info("number of disconnects:"+str(number_of_disconnects))

    def client_connected(self, gst_server_obj, rtsp_client_obj):
        logging.info('[INFO]: Client has connected')
        self.create_media_factories()
        self.clients_list.append(rtsp_client_obj)
        if self.verbosity > 0:
            logging.info('[INFO]: Client has connected')


    def stop_all(self):
        self.destroy_media_factories()

    def stop_by_index(self,path):
        self.destroy_media_factories_by_path(path)

    def get_paths(self):
        return self.media_path_list

    def get_status(self):

        mount_points = self.get_mount_points()
        session_pool = self.get_session_pool()
        # logging.info("Number of sessions are :" +
        #              str(session_pool.get_n_sessions()))
        number_of_disconnects = session_pool.cleanup()
        if number_of_disconnects > 0:
            logging.info("number of disconnects:"+str(number_of_disconnects))          
        for path in self.get_paths():
            sessions_list = session_pool.filter()
            for session in sessions_list:
                session.set_timeout(1)
                media_matched, _ = session.get_media(path)
                if media_matched:
                    rtsp_media = media_matched.get_media()
                    status = rtsp_media.get_status() #<enum GST_RTSP_MEDIA_STATUS_PREPARED of type GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaStatus>
                    
                    if "GST_RTSP_MEDIA_STATUS_UNPREPARING" in str(status):
                        # print(self.context)
                        # GObject.Object.unref(self)
                        # print(status)
                        # transport = media_matched.get_transport(0)
                        # transport.set_active(False)
                        # print(enum_list)
                        # print(rtsp_media.unprepare())
                        # rtsp_media.set_eos_shutdown(True)
                        # session.set_timeout(1)
                        # session.release_media(media_matched)
                        # session.allow_expire()
                        # session.release_media(media_matched)
                        # media_matched.set_state(Gst.State.PAUSED)
                        # media_matched.set_state(Gst.State.READY)
                        # media_matched.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
                        # rtsp_media.suspend()
                        # print(rtsp_media.unprepare())
                        # rtsp_media.set_pipeline_state(Gst.State.READY)
                        # rtsp_media.set_pipeline_state(Gst.State.NULL)
                        # rtsp_media.unprepare()
                        # self.client_filter()
                        print("removing")



    def status_thread_loop(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)
            try:
                self.get_status()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

    def __del__(self):
        print("Destroy called")

    def get_current_encoders_details(self):
        enc_details = dict()
        for i,cap in enumerate(self.caps):
            enc_details[i]={"path":self.media_path_list[i],"decoder":cap,"factory":self.factory[i]}
        return enc_details

    @staticmethod
    def get_ip():
        return subprocess.check_output("hostname -I", shell=True).decode('utf-8').split(' ')[0]



class encoders():
    """
    This is the containter for multiple encoders
    """

    def __init__(self,decoders=[],head=[],resolutions=[],suffix="video") -> None:
        self.encoder_list = []
        self.caps = decoders
        self.fps = 60
        Sizes = resolutions
        self.enc_obj = RTSP_utility_server(self.fps, Sizes=Sizes, speed_preset="medium", caps=decoders, suffix=suffix,
                                           verbosity=1, rtp_port=8554, ip='10.5.1.130')

    def get_encoders(self):
        return self.enc_obj.get_current_encoders_details()

    def set_frame(self,enc_id=0,frame=np.zeros((360, 640, 3))):
        encoder_objects = self.enc_obj.get_current_encoders_details()
        decoder_obj = None
        for id in self.enc_obj.get_current_encoders_details():
            if id == enc_id:
                decoder_obj = encoder_objects[id]["decoder"]
                break
        if decoder_obj:
            decoder_obj.set_canvas(frame)
        else:
            print("Decoder not available")


    def stop_all(self):
        self.enc_obj.stop_all()

    def stop_by_index(self,path="/video1"):
        self.enc_obj.stop_by_index(path)

    def get_status(self):
        self.enc_obj.get_status()
```

the mp queue logic is as following

```py
    while True:
            # print(f'Thread {self.media_id} Looking')
            if self.stop_signal.is_set():
                self.stop_signal.clear()
                self.active = False
                break

            ret, frame = self.capture.read()
            
            if ret and type(frame) != type(None):
                self.frame = frame.copy()
                self.latest_frame = frame.copy()
                self.recieving_signal.set()
                self.latest_frame_time = time.ctime()
                try:
                    self.frame_queue.put(self.frame,block=False)
                except Full:
                    pass
```

Here capture is cv2.VideoCapture from an offline file. Is there any way to improve the quality of the video without stuttering with new connections.

Comment: Did you verify that the server encoding performance can handle the needed pixels/s? One way to go could be to encode the videos frames once and for each stream just send them, without additional in-time encoding

Comment: Hi @Micka, thank you for the response since this is a special case where I should use the only GPU (nvh264enc -encoder) to encode the video I will not be able to use the specified way. Since the gstreamer library is somewhat restricted for that kind of use.

Comment: then please check, whether your requested streams are possible to be encoded in real-time on your GPU hardware. If not, you will have to buy more GPUs or limit the number of requested streams or reduce the resolution of the streamed videos. If you want to try a more sophisticated open source streaming server, have a look at live555 but tat will likely need some developmet time.

Comment: please determine if removing `cv2.resize` makes a difference.  if it does not, this isn't an OpenCV question.

Comment: Hello @Micka, we are already encoding video in nvidia 3050 GPU using nvenc plugin from gstreamer. And the utilization of the GPU encoder is below 30%, so it is not the Hardware capability.  The parallel videos run smoothly, but not the same video requested multiple times.

Comment: hi @ChristophRackwitz, It doesn't make a difference